# Classification with Features with Variable Sizes

Tags: deep-learning, classification

I have an experimental data collected from different subjects. Dataset is included breathing frequencies collected during experiments from multiple subjects and labeled by an observer as  emotions(a,b,c,...). If there is no emotion to observe the section is just left blank.

The duration of the subject showing the emotions differs. So the duration of the same emotion have variable sizes. I want to do 2 different classifications and measure performance using the same dataset if I can.

1. Classification of the Emotions (That is the main focus)
2. Classification of the Subjects

Dataset:
Here is an example from the dataset. Sub.1 is subject 1 and the frequency next to it belongs to the subject.

| Time (sec.) | Emotion(Sub. 1) | Frequency | Emotion(Sub. 2) | Frequency | Emotion(Sub. 3) | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 0.021519 | - | -0.003323 | - | 0.009087 |
| 2 | a | 0.022202 | a | -0.002048 | - | 0.008112 |
| 3 | a | 0.022249 | a | -0.000701 | a | 0.006830 |
| 4 | a | 0.021660 | a | 0.000715 | a | 0.006259 |
| 5 | a | 0.020457 | - | 0.002185 | - | 0.005483 |
| 6 | - | 0.018702 | - | 0.003673 | - | 0.004551 |
| 7 | - | 0.016470 | - | 0.005143 | - | 0.003532 |
| 8 | b | 0.013873 | - | 0.006537 | b | 0.002503 |
| 9 | b | 0.011012 | - | 0.007798 | b | 0.001531 |
| 10 | b | 0.022249 | b | 0.008860 | - | 0.000701 |
| 11 | - | 0.021660 | b | 0.009676 | - | 0.000069 |
| 12 | - | 0.020457 | b | 0.010200 | - | -0.000296 |
| 13 | - | 0.018702 | b | 0.010402 | a | -0.000350 |
| 14 | - | 0.016470 | - | 0.010272 | a | -0.000065 |
| 15 | - | 0.013873 | - | 0.009824 | a | 0.000574 |

I am planning to train a deep neural network for classification. I am still not sure how to transform the data so it can be feed to a neural network. I am still not sure how kind of model I should use. Any idea would be a great help.